# Effective way to calculate values for multiple dates?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

Right now I'm calculating totals for multiple dates in Google Spreadsheets, to make calculations for a week I take the start date and just do a `Filter()` for that day + 1 for the whole week.

An example:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = $B$1),0), IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+1)), 0), IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+2)), 0), IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+3)), 0), IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+4)), 0), IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+5)), 0), IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+6)), 0))
```

This is made up of multiple sections like this:

```
IFERROR(FILTER('HelpScout Import'!C:C, 'HelpScout Import'!$B:$B = $A3, 'HelpScout Import'!$A:$A = TO_DATE(N($B$1)+1)), 0)
```

This just filters the data by the start day + 1. `HelpScout Import'!$A:$A` is the date column. `TO_DATE(N($B$1)+1))` takes the date, turns it into a number, adds 1, then turns it back into a date.

If I wanted to compile data for an entire month, this type of function would be hilariously inadequate. Having 30 to 31 sections like the above would be unmanageable.

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: An easier way using `DSUM()`:

```
=DSUM('HelpScout Import'!A:H, "Total Conversations", ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE({"Date", H8, TO_DATE(N(H8)+1), TO_DATE(N(H8)+2), TO_DATE(N(H8)+3), TO_DATE(N(H8)+4), TO_DATE(N(H8)+5), TO_DATE(N(H8)+6)})))
```

However, this still means I need a `TO_DATE(N(H8)+1)` for every day. Looking for a way to create an array of dates within a single cells function.

Edit2: Made an apps script that returns an array of dates.

```
function GetNextXDays(startDay, days)
{
  var inputDate = new Date(startDay);
  var dates = [];
  for(i =0; i < days; i++)
  {
    var newDate = new Date(startDay);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);
    dates.push(newDate);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

This returns the dates I need thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `DSUM` with bigger and smaller operators to define a range.

```
=DSUM('HelpScout Import'!A:H, "Total Conversations", {{"Date"; JOIN("", ">=", TO_DATE(H8))}, {"Date"; JOIN("", "<=", TO_DATE(H8 + 30))}})
```

btw. `;` is used to define columns while `,` is used for rows. So by using `;` instead of `,` I get rid of the transpose statement.

edit:
Your `GetNextXDays` function is not working correctly. `new Date()` takes as an argument the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 while `DATEVALUE` and `TO_DATE` use the number of days since 12/30/1899.
Here is a better version of that function. 25569 is the number of days from 12/30/1899 to 1/1/1970. 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in a day.

```
function GetNextXDays(startDay, days)
{
  var dates = [];
  for(var day = startDay; day < startDay + days; day++)
  {
    var newDate = new Date((day - 25569) * 86400000);
    dates.push(newDate);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to get an array of dates to return. However I can't seem to `DSUM()` based on both name and date. Here is a picture of what my criteria looks like: http://i.imgur.com/XdIKcTF.png and my function: `=DSUM('HelpScout Import'!A:H, "Total Conversations", J17:K18)` J17:K18 refers to the first two rows of that picture. It just returns `0`

Comment: Scratch that, I figured it out. I need to have multiple "OR" like conditions. It now looks like: {{"Name"; A15}, {"Date"; ">="&B1}, {"Date"; "<="&D1}}

Comment: I found an error in your code and added a fix to my answer.